# Commutation of exponentials of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two $n \times n$ real matrices $A$ and $B$, prove that the following are equivalent:

(i) $\left[A,B\right]=0$

(ii) $\left[A,{\rm e}^{tB}\right] = 0,\quad$ $\forall\ t\ \in\ \mathbb{R}$

(iii) $\left[{\rm e}^{sA},{\rm e}^{tB}\right] = 0;\quad$ $\forall\ s,t\ \in\ \mathbb{R}$

where $\left[A,B\right] = AB - BA$ is the commutator.

First of all, this is homework, so no need for a complete answer. It is pretty easy to show that $\left(i\right)\Rightarrow\left(ii\right)$ and $\left(ii\right)\Rightarrow(iii)$. However, I have no idea for $\left(iii\right)\Rightarrow\left(i\right)$ other than explicitly writing the exponentials, and that doesn't seem to lead anywhere:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}
{s^{i}t^{\,j}\over i!\,j!}\,\left[A^{i},B^{\,j}\right]}.\qquad$
( I think... ) Any tips ?.

Comment: It's probably easiest to go $(iii) \Rightarrow (ii) \Rightarrow (i)$. Differentiate $f(s) = [e^{sA},e^{tB}] \equiv 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I see is to do it in two steps, proving $(iii) \Rightarrow (ii) \Rightarrow (i)$.

To prove $(iii) \Rightarrow (ii)$, differentiate $f(s) = [e^{sA},e^{tB}] \equiv 0$. The proof of $(ii) \Rightarrow (i)$ is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see! $f(s,t)\equiv [e^{sA};e^{tB}] \Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial s \partial t}=[Ae^{sA};Be^{tB}]  \equiv 0 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial s \partial t} (0,0)=[A;B]=0$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\partiald{\bracks{{\rm e}^{sA},{\rm e}^{tB}}}{s}
= \bracks{\expo{sA}A,\expo{tB}} = 0\,,\qquad
{\partial^{2}\bracks{{\rm e}^{sA},{\rm e}^{tB}} \over \partial t\,\partial s}
= \bracks{\expo{sA}A,\expo{tB}B} = 0
\end{align}
In particular, with $t = s = 0$: $\bracks{A,B} = 0$.